# How Can I Change Strings.xml by Clicking a Button?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to create 2 Strings.xml files.
One strings.xml file contains English words which are using in application.
The another one `strings.xml` file contains Another Language words.

And, I want to change my language files by clicking a Button. How Can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use localization and create the string file of the required language ..By the way  What language you want except english ? @gokhangocmen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on button click set setLangRecreate("ar") for arabic and save language preference for next time when app launch.

```
 public void setLangRecreate(String langval) {
            Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
            Locale locale = new Locale(langval);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            recreate();
        }
```

Comment: This only works for current activity, in my case... Does not work for ALL the app or activities nor fragments

Answer (score 0):

Create a new values folder with the country abbreviation, examples, strings for Egypt may be put in a `values-eg` folder and strings for China may be in `values-zh` or strings for Arabic may be in `values-ar`.

Android will automatically load the right file if available in any locale the app is being used in.

Comment: I want to change application language by clicking button without changing mobile phone's language. Is that not possible?

Comment: @vinay's answer should do the trick, pass his code in the onclick method